# how to design Mapper with two inputs in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have to implement two mapReduce jobs that Mapper_2 needs output of Reducer_1. Mapper_2 also needs another input that is a text file. How can I design mapper_2 with these two inputs? in the other word, how to define two input parameters in mapper_2 to be the output of the previous job in mapreduce and a text file?

Comment: Are you doing streaming or using the Java API?

Comment: What is the purpose of this text file?How big is it?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, the question is that you need two input paths with the same mapper. Am I right? If so, you can use:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(Job, TextInputPath, SomeInputFormat.class, Mapper_2.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(Job, Ruducer_1OutputPath, SomeInputFormat.class, Mapper_2.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. After Running job2, Is the existing output directory of Reducer1  overwritten by output of Reducer2? or it makes error that output exists??

Comment: No, if a directory already exists in HDFS the job will fail. If you want to output to a directory that already exists, you must first delete that directory. If you require the output of job 1 in job 2, simply use a different output directory for job 2.